# Flashpunk pixel perfect collision on a spritemap

Tags: actionscript-3, collision

I'm working on a kind of 2d platform ARPG in Flashpunk, and have run into somewhat of a conundrum.

Ranged weapons are no big deal.  They are a flat image that I move and rotate to emulate the feel of throwing or firing a ranged weapon.  Melee weapons are a bit more of a pain, as I want to use a sprite map for different weapon animations.

The problem I run into is that I have to manually adjust the hitbox for every frame of the melee weapon.  I would like to use the Pixelmask function included with Flashpunk, but it does not seem to work with Spritemap.  Is there a way to force it to work, or a way to convert the current frame of the Spritemap into an Image so I can apply a Pixelmask?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but what you could do is create a Vector of images separate from the animation itself, with indices equal to that of the corresponding animation, and create the pixelmask from there. If that ends up being too slow (dynamically allocated memory being slower than reusing preallocated), you could load the images, create pixelmasks from them, and push the pixelmasks to a vector instead. From there, all you would need to do is switch to the correct pixelmask during the attack animation.